# php Symfony Doctrine error al crear base de datos

Tags: php, xampp, symfony, macos, doctrine

tengo un proyecto en Symfony(Version 4.4.11)  y estoy intentando crear una base de datos con Doctrine.
Cuando ejecuto en la consola el siguiente comando

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

Me tira el siguiente error en la consola.

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:
                                                                              
  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  
                                                                              

In PDOConnection.php line 31:
                                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  
                                             

In PDOConnection.php line 27:
                                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  
                                             

doctrine:database:create [-s|--shard SHARD] [-c|--connection [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

Estoy programando en Mac y estoy usando XAMPP.
Debería tener alguna configuración en particular para que este comando funcione?
Alguna idea de como podria solucionarlo?
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: `Connection refused` significa que activamente se rechazó la conexión. Revisa en los logs de XAMPP, del lado de la BD para ver si hay algún registro relacionado. Puede ser un problema de credenciales, por ejemplo

Comment: Disculpa, a que te referis con los 'logs' de XAMPP? Si voy a la ventana 'log' de XAMPP me dice esto: INFO: Starting "XAMPP" stack
INFO: "XAMPP" stack successfully started
INFO: Starting "mysql"
INFO: Starting "proftpd"
INFO: Starting "apache"
INFO: Successfully started "mysql"
INFO: Successfully started "proftpd"
INFO: Successfully started "apache"
INFO: Restarting "mysql"
INFO: Successfully restarted "mysql" y me es poco util en este caso.

Comment: No. Logs, archivos con trazas. En mac deberían estar en `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql` o algo similar.